# How can I count the length of the edge associated with each point？

Tags: python, delaunay

I built the Delaunay triangulation in python.
Now I have 8 points (black) and generate 14 edges (gray).
How can I count the length of the edge associated with each point？
the matrix I want is the edges' length connected by each point, such as

```
[[P1, E1_length, E2_length, ...], [P2, E6_length, E7_length, ...], ...]
```

```py
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1],[1.5, 0.6],[1.2, 0.5],[1.7, 0.9],[1.1, 0.1],])
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.triplot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], tri.simplices.copy(), color='0.7')
plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'o', color='0.3')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New answer

Here's an approach which will give you a dictionary of points and edge lengths associated with each point:

```py
simplices = points[tri.simplices]
edge_lengths = {}

for point in points:
    key = tuple(point)
    vertex_edges = edge_lengths.get(key, [])
    adjacency_mask = np.isin(simplices, point).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)
    for simplex in simplices[adjacency_mask]:
        self_mask = np.isin(simplex, point).all(axis=1)
        for other in simplex[~self_mask]:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(point - other)
            if dist not in vertex_edges:
                vertex_edges.append(dist)
    edge_lengths[key] = vertex_edges
```

Output:

```
{(0.0, 0.0): [1.4142135623730951, 1.1, 1.3, 1.0],
 (0.0, 1.1): [1.004987562112089, 1.3416407864998738, 1.4866068747318506],
 (1.0, 0.0): [1.4866068747318506, 0.5385164807134504, 0.7810249675906654, 1.140175425099138, 0.14142135623730956],
 (1.0, 1.0): [1.004987562112089, 1.4142135623730951, 0.5385164807134504, 0.6403124237432849, 0.7071067811865475],
 (1.5, 0.6): [0.6403124237432849, 0.36055512754639896, 0.31622776601683794, 0.6403124237432848],
 (1.2, 0.5): [0.5385164807134504, 1.3, 0.31622776601683794, 0.41231056256176607],
 (1.7, 0.9): [0.7071067811865475, 0.36055512754639896],
 (1.1, 0.1): [0.14142135623730956, 0.41231056256176607, 0.6403124237432848]}
```

### Old answer before requirements changed

The `Delaunay` object has a `simplices` attribute which returns the points which make up the simplices. Using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()`, and advanced indexing, you can get all the edge lengths like so:

```py
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

>>> edge_lengths = np.array([pdist(x) for x in points[tri.simplices]])
>>> edge_lengths
array([[1.00498756, 1.41421356, 1.1       ],
       [0.53851648, 1.3       , 1.41421356],
       [0.53851648, 1.        , 1.3       ],
       [0.64031242, 0.70710678, 0.36055513],
       [0.64031242, 0.31622777, 0.53851648],
       [0.14142136, 0.53851648, 0.41231056],
       [0.64031242, 0.41231056, 0.31622777]])
```

Note however, that edge lengths are duplicated here, since every simplex shares at least one edge with another simplex.

### Step-by-step

The `tri.simplices` attribute gives the indices in `points` for each vertex in each simplex in the Delaunay object:

```py
>>> tri.simplices
array([[2, 6, 5],
       [7, 2, 5],
       [0, 7, 5],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 7],
       [0, 3, 7],
       [3, 1, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

Using advanced indexing, we can get all the points which make up the simplices:

```py
>>> points[tri.simplices]
array([[[1. , 1. ],
        [0. , 1.1],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[1.2, 0.5],
        [1. , 1. ],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[1. , 0. ],
        [1.2, 0.5],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[1. , 1. ],
        [1.5, 0.6],
        [1.7, 0.9]],

       [[1.5, 0.6],
        [1. , 1. ],
        [1.2, 0.5]],

       [[1. , 0. ],
        [1.1, 0.1],
        [1.2, 0.5]],

       [[1.1, 0.1],
        [1.5, 0.6],
        [1.2, 0.5]]])
```

Finally, each subarray here represents a simplex and the three points which form it, and by using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()`, we can get the pairwise distances of each point in each simplex by iterating over the simplices:

```py
>>> np.array([pdist(x) for x in points[tri.simplices]])
array([[1.00498756, 1.41421356, 1.1       ],
       [0.53851648, 1.3       , 1.41421356],
       [0.53851648, 1.        , 1.3       ],
       [0.64031242, 0.70710678, 0.36055513],
       [0.64031242, 0.31622777, 0.53851648],
       [0.14142136, 0.53851648, 0.41231056],
       [0.64031242, 0.41231056, 0.31622777]])
```

Comment: Through your method, I get the index of each triangulation's vertex and the edges' length matrix. 
But the matrix I want is  the edges' length connected by each point, such as
[[P1, E1_length,  E2_length, E3_length, E4_length, E5_length ],  
[P2, E6_length,  E7_length, E1_length, E8_length, E9_length ], 
...]

Comment: @user17075520 I updated my answer but perhaps you didn't see it. There are many modifications you can make to this code, depending on the exact structure of the output that you desire. Your desired outcome of `[[P1, |E1|, |E2|, ...], ...]` isn't particularly clear, since `Pi` is an `(x, y)` coordinate but `|Ej|` is a scalar, so I went with a dictionary where each key in the dictionary is one of the points in the triangulation, and the value is a list of lengths of edges connected to that point.

Comment: For the code: if dist not in vertex_edges:
                vertex_edges.append(dist)   When different edges (connected to one point) have the same length, the edges had been removed too.